# How can I set the 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I am done with my requirements and I am unable to build my app. It is simply throwing an error like:

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. 
Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. 
Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

Can anyone suggest me how to rectify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the below lines in `.bash_profile` file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/YOUR_PATH_TO/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: In which location (.bash_profile file) this file have? i have only .bashrc file by default. Do i have to create any file with .bash_profile file??

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: @Ashok No append the changes suggested by Haritha in .bashrc file

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Even though i appended those paths it is repeating the same error

Comment: have you given exact path of sdk directory in ANDROID_HOME? check the path once again.. where sdk's are downloaded..

Comment: Yeah every thing is perfect here except the ERROR.

Comment: please follow this link:   
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Comment: Still here except the same ERROR...!